# Show discount percentage in WooCommerce sale button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to show the percentage of discount in the sale bubble in WooCommerce. Here is an image how the button looks now:

[image]

So, basically, the button will show: -20%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to hook into the `woocommerce_sale_flash` filter, grab the product object, work out the percentage and add it to the HTML.

Something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_bubble' );
function add_percentage_to_sale_bubble( $html ) {
    global $product;
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    $output =' <span class="onsale">VERKOOP -'.$percentage.'%</span>';
    return $output;
}
```

---

### Edit - Variable Products:

With variable products getting thrown into the mix, you will need to include a check using `is_type('simple|variable')` and adjust your calculations from there, like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_bubble', 20 );
function add_percentage_to_sale_bubble( $html ) {
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('simple')) { //if simple product
        $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 ).'%';
    } else { //if variable product
        $percentage = get_variable_sale_percentage( $product );
    }
    
    $output =' <span class="onsale">-'.$percentage.'</span>';
    return $output;
}

function get_variable_sale_percentage( $product ) {
    //get variables
    $variation_min_regular_price    = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_regular_price    = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);
    $variation_min_sale_price       = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_sale_price       = $product->get_variation_sale_price('max', true);

    //get highest and lowest percentages
    $lower_percentage   = round( ( ( $variation_min_regular_price - $variation_min_sale_price ) / $variation_min_regular_price ) * 100 );
    $higher_percentage  = round( ( ( $variation_max_regular_price - $variation_max_sale_price ) / $variation_max_regular_price ) * 100 );
    
    //sort array
    $percentages = array($lower_percentage, $higher_percentage);
    sort($percentages);

    if ($percentages[0] != $percentages[1] && $percentages[0]) {
        return $percentages[0].'% - '.$percentages[1].'%';
    } else {
        return $percentages[1].'%';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thnx. Where do i add this code? In the functions.php?

Comment: Hi @ArjanWassink - Yeah, drop it inside your functions.php - I've just updated the code, to make sure that the percentage is __inside__ the bubble, so make sure you re-copy it from here :)

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors? I've tested this on one of my own sites and it worked perfectly fine. Where did you add this?

Comment: I'm not getting any erros at all. The button keeps displaying "VERKOOP", but no descount percentage. I pasted this code in the functions.php of my theme.

Comment: Did you get my message?

Comment: @Delerious yeah - just haven't been near my testing environment to double check anything - should hopefully have some help ready for you around wednesday! In the mean time, which version of woocommerce are you using? Also, what happens if you add a priority to the filter? Like this: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'add_percentage_to_sale_bubble', 20 );`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 3.4.3. Ill check if the priority works. I'll let you know :)

Comment: Checked the priority (not sure how it works): I've pasted it in the code and it seems to work. However, it's not showing the right percentage now.

Comment: check power-light.nl/sale

Comment: I think it's not showing the right percentage due to some products being variable products. It does show correctly on simple products though ;)

Comment: Ah, ofcourse - that makes sense! I've added changes in an edit to account for variations, however like I mentioned, I am nowhere near a testing environment right now, will only be able to test this around Wednesday. Hopefully it works, or puts you on the right path, otherwise, we will see what we can achieve in a few days time :)

Comment: Thanks! I made a few changes. I got rid of the double variable discount (it showed 15% - 15%, or 15% - 20% for products with variable discounts) 

Only problem now is that when i'm working with a variable product which has one variable with discount, and one without, it shows 0% in the button.

Comment: Awesome - I've approved the edit, change the bottom line to use the second array iteration like this: `$percentages[1]` - because we are sorting the array, the lowest number goes first (which is 0%), so going for the next iterator should fix that :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Frits! I've updated the code because there was a quote sign missing. Everything is working fine now, thanks again Frits :D

Comment: This works great!!. Only quote sign is missing in the last line. It should be: return $percentages[1].'%';

Comment: @Angom - thank you so much for picking that up - I've fixed it with an edit! Kudos!